# Threejs intersects[0].obj is undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm am trying to have a window open to a url link that has been attached to the objects userData.URL but im getting and "undefined" error. This is what my event looks like

```
function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objs);
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
    window.open(intersects[0].obj.userData.URL);
    }
```

and this is how im attaching the data within the init function

```
            obj = objs[i] = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            for (u; u < urllist.length; u++) {
            if (objs[i].userData.URL !== undefined){
                break;
            }
            idvurl=urllist[u];
            objs[u].userData = {URL: idvurl};
            }
```

EDIT: I messed up the variables when asking the question.

Comment: Right after attaching the data, you can log your `objs` object and take a look, if its elemets' `userData` property contains `.URL`.

Comment: raycaster.intersectObjects(objects) what is objects here ?

Comment: `for (u; u < urllist.length; u++) {` Here, `u = undefined` => `undefined < urllist.length` = ??; `undefined++` = ??.

Comment: -Prisoner849, I have  a log in my original code, The data is being attached. And u is declared as 0. Sorry for the misunderstandings.

Comment: Gor I fixed it in my question. My exact error is "intersects[0].obj is undefined"